# An exception occured in driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: nodename nor servname provided, or not known

Tags: symfony

I work with Symfony 3 on my first web site.
When I launch the web site locally, it work and the link with the local database is done.

But when I use the parameters of real database on OVH, I have this message :

An exception occured in driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: nodename nor servname provided, or not known

The two base are similar, it's a import of the local database.

I have this parameters :

```
    # This file is auto-generated during the composer install
    parameters:
        database_host: e********.mysql.db
        database_port: 21
        database_name: e********
        database_user: e********
        database_password: ********
        mailer_transport: smtp
        mailer_host: 127.0.0.1
        mailer_user: null
        mailer_password: null
        secret: ThisTokenIsNotSoSecretChangeIt
```

Comment: Maybe it has something to do with the version of your live db?

Comment: please check your hostname.

Answer (score 0):

This is a strange behavior on OVH may not be stable on shared host: Periodically, the alias host `xxx.mysql.db` is reset or the ip behind it changes and the access is lost for some time. Just wait till next day.